# $\int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt = \int_{x}^{1} f(t) dt \implies f(x) = 0 \forall x \in [0,1]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

$f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

$\int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt = \int_{x}^{1} f(t) dt \implies f(x) =  0 \forall x \in [0,1]$

I don't understand why I can say $f(1)=f(0)=0$.
My attempt is using FTC:

$\int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt = \int_{x}^{1} f(t) dt  \implies \int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt= \int_{1}^{x} -f(t) dt \implies f(x) = -f(x) \forall x \in (0,1) \implies f(x) =  0 \forall x \in (0,1)$. However, the statement is about $[0,1]$. How can I conclude for $f(0)$ and $f(1)$?

Thanks

Comment: you didn't conclude that $f(x)=-f(x)$. You only know that $\int_0^x f(t)dt = \int_0^x -f(t)dt$

Comment: @Yanko now differentiate.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Yes but this in fact solves the problem, because you get that $\int_0^x f(t) dt = 0$ hence differentiation leads to $f(x)=0$. However I don't know if we can differentiate because the OP didn't specify whether $f$ is continuous or not.

Comment: Surely you need more from $f$? Say, continuity?

Comment: I think the statment is false, because $f(x) =0$ for $(0,1), f(1)=1,f(0)=1$ satisfy the hypothesis but is not the null function on $[0,1]$...

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist, yes, sorry, I forgot. $f$ is continuous

Comment: @dude3221 Your example works but it is not continuous. The claim is true once you assume the continuity of $f$. Did you learn about the fundamental Theorem of calculus?

Comment: ohh, of course! my example was not continuous indeed, I must be tired. I know about TFC.

Comment: Use the continuity definition involving sequences. For instance, can you show $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }f\left ( \frac{1}{n} \right ) \neq f\left ( \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\left ( \frac{1}{n} \right ) \right )$ if $f(0)\neq0$?

Comment: @dude3221 Or, use that $\,\int_{0}^{1} f(t) dt = \int_{1}^{1} f(t) dt = 0\,$ and $\,\int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt + \int_{x}^{1} f(t) dt =  \int_{0}^{1} f(t) dt = 0\,$, then see [If $\int_0^x f \  dm$ is zero everywhere then $f$ is zero almost everywhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16244/if-int-0x-f-dm-is-zero-everywhere-then-f-is-zero-almost-everywhere).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$. If $\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt=\int_{x}^{1}f(t)dt$ for all $0 \le x \le 1$, then the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus gives
$$
       f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x f(t)dt=\frac{d}{dx}\int_x^1f(t)dt = -f(x)
$$

So $f(x)=0$ for $0 \le x \le 1$. (You take a right-hand derivative at $x=0$ and a left-hand derivative at $x=1$.)

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus is the weapon to use here. However, if you want to get your hands a little bit dirtier, notice that 
$$\int_0^x f(t)dt = \int_x^1f(t)dt = \int^1_0f(t)dt - \int_0^xf(t)dt$$
implies that
$$\int_0^x f(t)dt = \frac 12 \int_0^1 f(t)dt.$$
In particular, this also means (write the previous identity for $x=a$ and $x=b$, and substract them) that
$$\int_a^bf(t)dt = 0,\quad\forall a,b\in(0,1).$$
Finally, assume there exists $x_0\in(0,1)$ such that $f(x_0)>0$. Since $f$ is continuous, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)>\frac 12 f(x_0) > 0$ for each $|x-x_0|<\delta$ (definition of continuity with $\epsilon = \frac 12f(x_0)$). This implies that the integral of $f$ over $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ must be strictly positive, contradicting the previous equation. If you assume $f(x_0)<0$, an analogous reasoning follows.